# Connection issue between Sparrow and Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, sparrow-wallet

I currently have my Bitcoin Core node set up to utilize an external hard drive for the data directory in order to conserve space on my laptop. Initially, when I connected Sparrow to the node for the first time, everything went smoothly. However, subsequent attempts to use Sparrow have resulted in an error message stating, "Connection failed: Wallet file verification failed. Failed to create database path '/Volumes/External Hard Drive/cormorant'. Database already exists." To resolve this, I've been closing Sparrow, removing the cormorant folder from the data directory on the external hard drive, and then reopening Sparrow. Doing so creates a new cormorant folder, and everything functions correctly. I'm hoping to find a solution that eliminates the need to delete the cormorant folder each time I want to use Sparrow. Thank you for any assistance you can provide!